# XML Generation Error Installing SQL Server Express 2008 on Windows 8

Tags: sql-server-express, virtualbox, windows-8

**Disclaimer:** Yes, I know Windows 8 is a pre-release and things won't necessarily work. I still need to do this.

I'm trying to install SQL Server Express 2008 R2 on Windows 8 32-bit (via Virtual Box). When I run the installer, I get an error:

```
Database installer returned error code -2147024893 (The system cannot find the path specified.)
```

The web installer didn't work either. WPI's log file tells me:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'SQL Server Express 2008 R2' is -2068774911
```

I tried running this in compatibility mode for Windows 7. I can run the installer, click through the setup screen, and finally I get this error:

```
There was an error generating the XML document.

Error code: 0x84B10001.
```

How do I get this working, or, how do I debug/triage this? I looked through the logs, but I'm not too sure what they said; it might've been a registry-write error. Running in admin mode just causes the installer to not load, or a nice BSOD:

[image]

Comment: Don't hesitate to report any bugs that you encounter to Microsoft. Please don't report bugs on pre-release products on StackOverflow. It's just not the right place. StackOverflow is a programming related Q&A site. If you encounter some problems with a product that you are trying to install/use please contact the author.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov how exactly do I report it to them? They don't have Windows 8 developer preview for Connect, nor does their Windows feedback program cater to Windows 8.

Comment: Try here: http://www.mywindowsclub.com/resources/5092-How-report-bugs-Windows-Developer-Preview.aspx

Comment: @DarinDimitrov that just points to Microsoft Connect; like I mentioned, they're not handling Win8 bugs. I'll just file it under SQL Server, but I have a feeling it'll be ignored.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov there are enough SQL Server troubleshooting questions on SO that I felt comfortable asking mine here too. Just take a look at the Related section. I too believe these questions should be asked on SO.

Comment: excuse me but SQL Server installation questions are way off-topic on StackOverflow. They belong on http://servefault.com or http://superuser.com/. On the other hand of you are trying to write some program and have troubles executing/optimizing some specific SQL query don't hesitate asking on SO (obviously after showing the SQL query you have troubles with). Also it would be helpful to mention te programming language you are using in your tags or if you are trying to execute your SQL query directly using for example SQL Managment Studio. I think you get my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, ironically, is quite simple -- I was installing 32-bit SQL Server on a 32-bit Windows 8. Instead, I moved to installing a 64-bit SQL Server on a 64-bit Windows 8.

Problem solved.